# how to use variable in function outside

Tags: javascript

I have a problem while making code as a function.

this is my original code which is run well.

```
    var list = '<ul>';
    var o = 0;

    while (o < files.length) {
        list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${files[o]}'>${files[o]}</a></li>`;
        o++;
    }
    list = list + '</ul>';
    console.log(list);
```

and this is the function I made that doesn't work well.

```
function makeList(){
    var list = '<ul>';
    var o = 0;

    while (o < files.length) {
        list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${files[o]}'>${files[o]}</a></li>`;
        o++;
    }
    list = list + '</ul>';
    return;
}

makeList();
console.log(list);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Where is "files" defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Short answer... You defined the `list` variable inside of the function.  So it only exists inside of the function.

Comment: You can `return list;` in the function and then `console.log(makeList());`

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because list is not defined in the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/Glossary/Scope) you are trying to use it.

Also, you should not use while for iterating. Instead you should use a `for` loop (`for .. of` works really well):

```js
for(let file of files){
  //do something with file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is hoist the `list` variable up top, outside of the function.

The problem with this is that the function will always update `list`, instead of creating a new string.

```js
const files = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let list; // globally available

function makeList() {
  let o = 0;
  list = '<ul>';
  while (o < files.length) {
    list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${files[o]}'>${files[o]}</a></li>`;
    o++;
  }
  list = list + '</ul>';
}

makeList();
console.log(list);
```

You can simply this and make the function more reusable by:

- Passing in the `files`
- Using a for-loop
- Short-hand append (string concatenation)
- Returning the internal string

```js
function makeList(files) {
  let list = '<ul>';
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    list += `<li><a href='/?id=${files[i]}'>${files[i]}</a></li>`;
  }
  return list + '</ul>';
}

const list = makeList(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(list);
```

This can be further-reduced into a mapping (nesting template strings):

```js
const makeList = (files) => `
  <ul>
    ${files
      .map(file => `<li><a href='/?id=${file}'>${file}</a></li>`)
      .join('')}
  </ul>
`;

const list = makeList(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeList(){
    var list = '<ul>';
    var o = 0;

    while (o < files.length) {
        list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${files[o]}'>${files[o]}</a></li>`;
        o++;
    }
    list = list + '</ul>';
    return list;
}

const list = makeList();
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Add a description explaining what is happening i.e. variable scope and usage of `let/const` vs `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but just a little off at the end

```
  makeList() {
    const clothing = ['shoes', 'shirts', 'socks', 'sweaters'];

    let list = '<ul>';
    let o = 0;

    while (o < clothing.length) {
      list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${clothing[o]}'>${clothing[o]}</a></li>`;
      o++;
    }
    list = list + '</ul>';

    return list;
  }

  console.log(makeList());
```

The variable 'list' is only scoped for the function that it's in. So when you were trying to console.log it, it didn't exist.

Also, the function had a return at the end, but you didn't say what to return...

Finally, you're on the right track, but you might want to use .forEach or something similar - [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

```
  makeList() {
    const clothing = ['shoes', 'shirts', 'socks', 'sweaters'];
    let list = '<ul>';
    clothing.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(item, index);
      list = list + `<li><a href='/?id=${clothing[item]}'>${clothing[item]}</a></li>`;
    });
    list = list + '</ul>';

    return list;
  }

  console.log(makeList());
```